# How do I add a counter value into a cell once a row is added

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I work for a small company that monitors all service calls in an old database. I recently moved this database into a Google Spreadsheet and a Google Form.

Once a user submits a ticket, I would like column B at the same row to increase a counter such as

> 2014-0001, 2014-0002 and so on...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your spreadsheet and goto Tools>Script editor.  If this asks you what type of script to create choose spreadsheet.

This will generate a script page with some sample code in it.  You can leave that in or delete it.  It won't affect the following.

You can copy and paste this code in, make sure you save it.

```
function increment(e) {
  // Returns the sheet that has been updated by the form
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 

  // Returns the position of the last row that has content, 
  // presumably has just been updated
  var lastRow    = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Returns the position of the last counter cell   
  var lastCell   = sheet.getRange(lastRow,2); 

  // Reads the last value of the conter
  var inc        = lastCell.getValue(); 

  // Writes the incremented value to the new last position
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(inc+1); 
}
```

Now you have to set a trigger to run the function every time the form submits.

- Still in the code editor goto Resources > Current project's triggers
- In the pop up window select 'Add a new trigger'
- In the 1st drop down select the function name 'increment'
- In the 2nd drop down select the 'From Spreadsheet'
- In the 3rd drop down select the 'On form submit'

If you want to you can set an email notification to tell you when the script has run

Comment: To really finish it off, you can use: `.setValue(Utilities.formatString('2014-%04d',inc+1))`

Comment: thank you for this, however i get an error when running the script: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "SC number")

Comment: If you are using (e) it need a trigger e = event.  If you run it from the script editor e is undefined.  You can get round this if you rename the function from (e) to () and have only one sheet in the spreadsheet.  Replace the line var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet(); with var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();   If you have more than one sheet then use  var sheetRec   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAME OF SHEET");